# adding a file to the Hadoop Distributed cache

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I've a bunch of files that I need to access in my mapper class. My assumption is if I package those files into my job jar file I don't need to put them in the DistributedCache because the jar file is copied to all nodes as a whole and when gets extracted those file will be there? Am I making the right assumption?
If not, is there anyway to ship those files along with my jar files and not to copy them to the HDFS separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can include them inside your jar. Depending upon the size of the size, you will have network bandwidth usage.

Using distributed cache is also good option, to ship files, zip files or jar files. You can use each option separately when you run the Hadoop jar command. The files would just be moved to the task nodes and be available to the application jar. One difference for moving jar files(map reduce dependent jars) is that, they would added to the class path for the mp reduce jar to run. For others like files and zip files, they would just be moved to the task nodes.